# Array Sorting give the error Error: Cannot use object of type Organization\System Policies Object as array"

Tags: php

When I Print my Array it give me as

```
print_r($out)
```

gives the below

```
Array
(
[0] => Organization\System Policies Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 780
        [name:protected] => Apply For all
    )

[1] => Organization\System Policies Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 779
        [name:protected] => Apply Critical   
    )

[2] => Organization\System Policies Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 781
        [name:protected] => Test Machines
    )

[3] => Organization\System Policies Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 782
        [name:protected] => Dev Systems  
    )
)
```

I tried the following code to sort it

```
$sorted = array();
    foreach ($out as $key => $row)
    {
        $sorted[$key] = $row['name'];
    }
    array_multisort($sorted, SORT_ASC, $out);
```

I Tried to Sort the array by using the "name" i am getting an errors as "Error: Cannot use object of type Organization\System Policies Object as array"  is there a way i can sort this.

Comment: Use `$row->name` as it's object, not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be careful your data object in your array you cant acess $row['name'] should be $row->name ....

```
 
 uasort($out,fn ($prev,$next)=>$prev->name<=>$next->name);

  print_r($out);
```

for version 7.4 below version

```
 $sortedArray=uasort($array,function($prev,$next){
     
     return $prev->name<=>$next->name;
});

print_r($sortedArray);
```

for iterate your data with foreach

```
foreach($out as $item)
{
    echo $item->name ; //will work
    echo  $item['name']//will not working
}
```

through ArrayObject with oop

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($out);
$arrayObject->uasort(function ($a,$b){
    return $a->name<=>$b->name;
});
print_r($arrayObject->getArrayCopy());
```

Comment: When I tried this i am getting an error Error: Cannot access protected property Organization\System Policies::$name

Comment: u cant access  proctected variable normally ,there are two ways to do this,
1.with closure 
for example 
``
class Example
{
  protected  $name='dılo';

}


echo (function(){   return $this->name; })->call(new Example()); //dılo

```


2. With Reflection object
```
class Foo { protected $bar; }
$foo = new Foo();

$rp = new ReflectionProperty('Foo', 'bar');
$rp->setAccessible(true);
echo $rp->getValue($foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is an array of objects, not an array of associative arrays. You can change your syntax to: `$sorted[$key] = $row->name;` or if you want it as an associative array you can type cast it:

```
$row = (array)$row;
$sorted[$key] = $row['name'];
```